# Check if field is in abstract model class

Tags: django, django-models

How can I check if a Model Field is in the abstract model?

I want to write a custom model_to_dict function that, only gives the field of the Abstract Model and not the related model.

So i want to exclude every field that is not in the abstract model, is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
hasattr(AbstrctModel, 'attr_name1')
```

If it returns `True` then its in the model.